# Tabular data (cancer dataset) reshaping format and prepare for classification

Tags: reshape

I have a dataset for cancer and non-cancer patients and would like to prepare it for classification.

Each sample has 4 columns and 1298 rows. The total number of samples is 68. So my `X_train` shape is: `(68, 1298, 4)` and `Y_train` shape is `(68)`.

Now, if I reshape the data to be in 2D array, how can I tell the model to separate these 68 samples?

My question is: how should I reshape the dataset and how should be the input shape format to the model?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. The basic method is to just concatenate everything in a sample, so you obtain 1298 * 4 columns for every sample. For a more specific answer you should probably give more detail about what the data represents.

Answer (score 0):

To make the data amenable to machine learning, each row should be an instance and each column should be a feature.

You state that you have 68 samples/instances, those are the rows. It is unclear from your description how to structure the 1298 x 4 dimensions. One brute force method is to take the Cartesian product which would result in 5,192 columns/features. The result is a matrix that is 68x5192 and ready for classification. The number of columns/features may be reduced through feature engineering and/or feature selection.